# Python Code to press "show more" on Robinhood, then extract the paragraph in the ABout section for a company

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to write a code to extract the paragraph in the about section on Robinhood for specific companies. The problem is that I need to press the show more button before I can access the full paragraph. I have written a code in the image attached and I was unsuccessful in pressing the show more button, then access the full paragraph to extract it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTE47.png)
I tried this code to press the show more button, to be able to access the full paragraph in the about section, but I was unable to do that.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score 0):

Off-topic (can't comment as I have insufficient reputation) but taking a cursory look at some examples it seems like Robinhood gets its company descriptions from MarketWatch (or at least the same place MarketWatch does).

MarketWatch is easier to scrape from as it doesn't appear to have a "Show More" button and the text is in an element with the CSS class `description__text`:

[image: HOOD MarketWatch description text as HTML]

Compare the [Robinhood description of AAPL](https://robinhood.com/us/en/stocks/AAPL/) and the [MarketWatch page's description of the same](https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/aapl):

[image: Robinhood description of AAPL]

[image: MarketWatch description of AAPL]

The only difference is that Robinhood includes the listed name (e.g., `The listed name for AAPL is Apple Inc. Common Stock.`). Unless you need this data I recommend scraping from MarketWatch.